# Can double-hyphens in strings be escaped?

Tags: mysql, delphi

i have an delphi application that sends MySQL queries to our server. The following query fails

```
INSERT INTO `KPT`.`Internalorders` 
  (`InternalOrderId`, `UserId`, `Text`, `MailSent`, 
   `Done`, `PartlyDone`, `Ordered`) 
VALUES (0, NULL, '- Teststring -- Teststring -', NULL, 1, 1, 1)
```

with this error message:

> MySQL Error Code: (1064)
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''- Teststring' at line 1

It looks like the string gets wordwrapped internally in the third-party-components i use for database access (MySQLDAC) and forms to

```
'- Teststring 
-- Teststring -'
```

which would lead to treating the second part as a comment. Because i dont have the possibility to change the third-party tools, i'm hoping that theres is a way to escape double-hyphens.

Is there?

Comment: Use parameters and all your problems will go away :)

Comment: What you mean specifically? Is it possible to deactivate the hyphen parsing by parameters? Oh you mean at the Query object, instead of filling my string in the query.text property?

Comment: yes indeed, so your query becomes: `INSERT INTO `KPT`.`Internalorders` (`InternalOrderId`, `UserId`, `Text`, `MailSent`, `Done`, `PartlyDone`, `Ordered`) VALUES (0, NULL, :Text, NULL, 1, 1, 1)` and assign the Text parameter in your query

Comment: So simple. That did it. Thank you! Odd - Never worked with the parameters, but working with these components since 5 years. Please add your comment as answer for me to accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can solve this using parameters and it will yield you several big advantages:

- no problems with strings and quotes (as you found out)
- resiliency against [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).
- Reusable & fast update queries (just change the parameter value and execute again)
- Query is easier to read and maintain.

So your query becomes:

```
INSERT INTO `KPT`.`Internalorders` 
  (`InternalOrderId`, `UserId`, `Text`, `MailSent`, 
   `Done`, `PartlyDone`, `Ordered`) 
VALUES (0, NULL, :Text, NULL, 1, 1, 1)
```

Assign the `Text` parameter via the [`Params`](https://www.microolap.com/products/connectivity/mysqldac/help/tmysqlquery_properties_params.htm) object or use the [`ParamByName`](https://www.microolap.com/products/connectivity/mysqldac/help/tmysqlquery_methods_parambyname.htm) method on the query object and execute it.

Comment: Thank you. One last question: Why easier to read? Seems like i cannot see the text strings at all then. Can these be seen in any logs?